# Is it possible to access the source excel document from share path using TOS for Big Data

Tags: talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Big Data and based on this created jobs to pull the data from source (Excel) to mongoDB. It is working fine.

Now, I'm trying to pull the source file from shared path. But i don't have an idea to do this.

Is it possible to pull the data from share path file?

Comment: You could try to download its file on your local machine (which component you should use depends on where `share path file` located) and then delete local copy of it in tPostjob

Comment: yes, it is possible. if you have access to the shared directory, you can keep its full path. Otherwise as mentioned by @Limmy you can pull it to your local and then use it.